# PHP Not finishing loop through URLS with SimpleHTMLDOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to use SimpleHTMLDom to rip data from the web and I'm having difficulty with performing requests to large numbers of pages.

I tried this approach with smaller numbers of requests with great success, but for the project I'm undergoing, I need to make requests to the web many many times.  Several hundred, in fact.

I have successfully made requests to the web 22 times and I am not finishing the loop.

Could this be a limitation within PHP, or the site itself not allowing that many requests?

Any help or thoughts on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
include "simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php";
error_reporting(0);

function scrape() {
   // Create HTML DOM (HTML structure and contents)
   $urls = array();
   $urls[] = "http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/hdfForecast?query=35203";
   $urls[] = "http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/hdfForecast?query=35813";
   ... // TWO HUNDRED MORE URLS

   // HTML Formatting

   foreach($urls as $url){
      $html = file_get_html($url);

      // PARSE DOM

      $html->clear();
      unset($html);
   }

   // MORE FORMATTING
}

// Set the user agent to the Mozilla Firefox

$ret = scrape();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has a limitation of 30 seconds for executing php codes . so you need to add this code at top of your php code :

```
set_time_limit(0);
```